# Filter one column and insert value in another column of all filtered rows

Tags: excel, vba

Can I make a VBA that selects all filtered cells of a column and adds a value to the next column to the right?

I.e., I have a list of workers and their current overtime in hours (column L).
I want to filter Column L to >10, and then inserts a "1" in each cell that is shown of column M (so I get a "1" for everyone who worked more than 10 hours of overtime).

Currently I have

```
    Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=">10", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
```

which does the filter-part, but I'm at a loss of how to then select the cells in column M and insert a value into them.

Very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(,1).Value = 1
```

Btw you almost always don’t need any selection and can more safely use fully qualified (up to worksheet object) range references

Comment: Thank you VERY much! This seems to work perfectly. 
(I will also look into how to use fully qualified range references. I'm still very very much a newbie to VBA so thanks for the help)